# Solution Curve Plot with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this Dynamical System learning, and I want to know how to plot this curve using Tikz. I tried Julia, but then think maybe Tikz can accomplish this better.

Thanks before!

[image]

Comment: You have a parametrization, so you can draw it as a [parametric plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278947/52406).

Comment: Maybe like thsi: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209168/47927